# Getting Undefined Mixin: box-sizing when using Sass in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, grid, sass

I have correctly installed Sass for WordPress. Now on the moment the plugin tries to read the scss file, I get this

```
<!--
 WPSASS ERROR - Error Parsing SASS File 
  Undefined Mixin: box-sizing: D:\Hosting\12006171\html/wp-content/themes/html5blank-master\mystyle.scss::1
Source: *
-->
```

the same error has occurred in Scout. I am new to all this and have no idea what to do. I have read about Compass, not  sure how to use it or this would solve the problem.

I just modified a Sass grid that I found online and implemented the Sass plugin for WordPress. I don't have no further info about what else I can do to make it run...

Comment: Well, without seeing the actual error message I'll have to guess based on your post title: sounds like you're trying to use a mixin via an `@include` rule, but it doesn't exist. You need to define your mixin first using `@mixin`. See [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide/#6)

Comment: Your error line is not visible. Paste it in a code block or write it in the question

Comment: WPSASS ERROR - Error Parsing SASS File 
  Undefined Mixin: box-sizing: D:\Hosting\12006171\html/wp-content/themes/html5blank-master\mystyle.scss::1
Source: *
-->

Comment: sorry guys, so above the error in wordpress. now i have installed compass on ruby and i get the same message. i get that i have to define the mixin first but i can not find out how.. also it seems most tutorials are for mac. However.. i am getting closer... can anybody help me how to define this line: * {
 @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

Comment: Please, use proper capitalization when writing here and check http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

Since you've installed Compass, you can use the box-sizing mixin that Compass provides.  Just include this in your Sass:

```
@import "compass/css3/box-sizing"
```

For more, see http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_sizing/.